# My wiki was working fine until now, suddenly this error is occouring, What can be done?

Tags: php, hash, mediawiki, wiki

This is the error

> Warning: hash(): Unknown hashing algorithm: fnv132 in
>   C:\wamp64\www\wiki\includes\resourceloader\ResourceLoader.php on line
>   624

Version info of my wiki

```
MediaWiki   1.32.2
PHP 7.2.18 (apache2handler)
MySQL   5.7.26
ICU 63.1
```

This is the part of code from resourceloader.php

```
623:  public static function makeHash( $value ) {
624:  $hash = hash( 'fnv132', $value );
625:  return Wikimedia\base_convert( $hash, 16, 36, 7 );
626:  }
```

My pages are loading fine in the background but this error banner is appearing over them, blocking half the page.

Comment: `fnv132` was added in PHP 5.4, so I'm left wondering if you don't actually have PHP 7.

Answer (score 0):

Probably all you have to do is reboot the server, and restart all the services in wamp. This should fix the problem.

If not, add this line to localSettings.php file in the root directory, then run the website via the browser. It should tell you if this hashing algorithm is enabled or not.

```
print_r(hash_algos());
```